# Responding with "יתברך" during Kaddish

Tags: tefilla, kaddish

Some have the custom of adding "יתברך" to the end of their "יהא שמה" response to Kaddish. What is the source of and explanation for this practice? Which minhagim would practice it?

Comment: "Adding" Why assume they are adding, and not everyone else is taking away?

Comment: Good point! I suppose I feel like I'm adding because I'm saying something additional compared to most in my current shul although I don't know which is the more common generally.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%95#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A0.D7.95_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93

Comment: I would assume "adding" rather than "taking away" because every siddur I've seen that breaks the text into paragraphs breaks before *yitbarakh*.

Comment: "(The poskim dispute whether one should also add “yisbarach” to this sentence, the Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chayim 56:3] ruling that one should, and the Gr”a ruling that one should not.)  "http://rabbikaganoff.com/proper-prayer-rejoinders-or-to-brich-or-not-to-brich/

Comment: I'm uncertain if OP is looking for some reasoning behind the dispute, rather than just what the opinions are. There are some interesting articles that discuss this reasoning. Thus, I am uncertain if this should be closed as a dupe. Jakub, please edit and / or comment if you want this type of info.

Answer (score 1):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch chapter 15 laws of kaddish, barechu, requirements of a minyan, & laws for the tzibur paragraph 2 towards the end... "amain yehai shmai rabba etc is said along with word "yisbarach"."

There is also a note at the bottom which says, "the Tur and the Rambam rule that the response should only be until olmaya. The shuchan aruch rules that "yisbareich" should also be said. Both customs are prevalent."

Comment: This is a partial answer. It is a source for what should be done. I think OP wnats the reasoning behind it.

Comment: You could make the questions stronger and ask why not just respond Amen instead of repeating part of Kaddish. Since no direct reason is given it simply sounds like a disagreement of which response is the correct mesora from the time of when kaddish was established